# Two Separate Map Providers in One App

Tags: ios, mapbox, apple-maps

A project that I'm working on for a client makes extensive use of maps. One of their app features is offline map usage. Therefore I preferred them Mapbox.

They're on board with Mapbox but now they're asking if it's possible two use Mapbox only for when the user goes offline and use Apple Maps while the user is online. The reasoning behind this is that Mapbox is only free until 50k usage. They're trying to get around the payment if possible.

Technically I know this is possible but what I can't decide is that will this situation have any downsides in the long run besides it's technical difficulties like having to maintain two map APIs? Does anything concrete pop up into your minds that I can use to convince the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've implemented multiple map providers on several occasions.  My tactic is to use a provider interface so the application isn't coupled to the map implementation.

There are a couple of downsides you could bring up with them.

- It's extra work
- The API's are architectured differently.  For example MapBox iOS uses delegates for marker annotations but Google maps uses member variables.  It requires you to structure your interface to account for the differences and inhibit certain features that one engine brings to the table (custom annotations and style sheets stick out to me as pain points)
- They have different capabilities and performance characteristics.
- Updates.  MapBox for example has more frequent updates as it's comparatively new.  This has implications for future work.
- User experience. Arbitrarily swapping map engines in certain conditions can be a little jarring for the user as they look and feel differently.  The times I've done it was as a feature for the user to choose their engine.

I guess the salient point is that the cost of the MapBox licensing is very cheap compared to the developer time trying to circumvent it. Additionally, the 50k uses is a problem for when the app becomes popular / successful.

Answer (score -1):

"Extensive use of maps" is ambiguous.  Extensive use of vehicles would not explain whether we're talking about truck drivers or F1 racers.  Please expand.